# vba excel autofit a region excluding several cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to autofit columns A:C without considering cells B2:B6 (I want those cells to contain long strings). 
Is there a way to tell excel to ignore those cells when autofitting?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: I can give you the answer but do you want to try and record a macro and see what do you get? Autofit Col A first and then Col C. It is a two line code :)

Comment: I've tried but I don't even know how to record it, because when I do it manually I have to set the width of cells B2:B6 manually.. The problem is that I still want column B to be autofitted according to all its cells apart from cells B2:B6

Comment: `The problem is that I still want column B to be autofitted according to all its cells apart from cells B2:B6` In that case see Gary's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a macro:

1. save B2:B6 elsewhere
2. autofit cols A thru C
3. restore B2 thru B6 from your temporary storage.

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want. You could also modify to autofit the Selected cells:

```
Sub Fit_Column_to_Some_Cells()
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$A,$C:$C,$B$1,$B$7:$B$1048576")
rng.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```